# 4.3 issue on nexus 4 while taking screenshot

Tags: nexus-4, screenshots, 4.3-jelly-bean

I've just upgraded my nexus 4 from 4.2.2 to 4.3 few days ago. And now i found that i can't take screenshots with volume down button + screen lock button anymore. It was working perfect on 4.2.2.

Anyone having same issue? Or it's just me? Any workout for this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I would recommend wipe Dalvik cache and cache and try again it will work. If not then try reflashing the stock rom.
And the only way to clear dalvik without root would be to factory reset your phone as cache and dalvik get cleared during this process.
For advanced help visit http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=1907#root

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and restarting my phone fixed it. Try rebooting your cell if you haven't done it yet.